# wsdl definition not being updated even after closing iis site

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wsdl, iis-express

I am using visual studio pro 2012 edition, one of our developers updated the wsdl definitions on a webservice without telling us and for a while i couldnt figure out why the wsdl definitions werent being updated. I did clean and build of the services, stopped the site and even exited IIS Express. Turns out if you have the solution open in visual studio with the old wsdl definition, the new definitions are not updated after pulling latest(svn). I tried several times and the only solution is to close visual studio and restart using the latest codebase.

anyone else experience this? could be a bug in vs2012 only?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what happened, my colleague copied over the hidden  folder .vs folder which had the applicationhost.config file pointing to their username, vs2012 does not give any errors and happily runs the service but it serves the old pages. VS2015 shows an error page which is how i found out the problem.